# How to convert a float into an unsigned int in C++?

Tags: c++, unsigned-integer

I want to convert a float to an unsigned int. When I use this code, the terminal print 3 :

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  float test = 3.4;
  std::cout << "test : " << int(test) << "\n";
}
```

But when I use this code I have an error :

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  float test = 3.4;
  std::cout << "test : " << unsigned int(test) << "\n";
}
```

My error is :

```
example.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
example.cc:5:29: error: expected primary-expression before ‘unsigned’
    5 |   std::cout << "test : " << unsigned int(test) << "\n";
      |
```

Can someone help me ? I need to use an unsigned int.
Thanks !

Comment: `unsigned(test)` for a function style cast or better: `static_cast<unsigned int>(test)`. 
Both of them round down.

Comment: It works ! Thanks !

Comment: Might also consider `printf`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *functional cast* (`type(expr)`, that is) requires the type to be spelled as a single word (without spaces, `[]`, `*`, `&`, etc).

`unsigned int` is not a single word, so it's not allowed.

Your options are:

- Using the regular C-style cast: `(unsigned int)test`.
- Omitting the `int`. `unsigned` alone means the same thing as `unsigned int`, so you can write `unsigned(test)`.
- Using a `static_cast`: `static_cast<unsigned int>(test)`.

Comment: Can you do a _functional cast_ to a `unsigned int` if it’s typedef’d?

Comment: @Dai Yes you can, because the typedef itself would be spelled as a single word.